# R requires a package (hms) to import a dataset. I install the package nothing happens. How do I install it properly?

Tags: r, import, huawei-mobile-services

UPDATE: The commenter below was of great help and described the solution accurately.

I'm a masters student trying to import data stored in .dta files in a folder on my desktop.

In my R Studio environment, I click a button "import dataset" (which I have used successfully in the past numerous times) and it gives me an error: "there is no package called hms".

Error message here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFcGZ.png

I went into the "packages" viewer and hit "install" to install the package hms without changing defaults. You can see the window here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqTp4.png

UPDATE: After manually installing the packages lifecycle, hms, and rlang, this is now what my screen looks like when attempting to import a dataset from stata. My going hypothesis is now that my current error has nothing to do with packages I'm trying to install. I think I've cleared that hurdle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCJLZ.png

The below markup is the exact output I get when installing hms.

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/nfeld/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘lifecycle’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
lifecycle  0.2.0  1.0.0             FALSE
hms        0.5.3  1.0.0             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘hms’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 83389 bytes (81 KB)
downloaded 81 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hms_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 42765 bytes (41 KB)
downloaded 41 KB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/nfeld/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/nfeld/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/hms'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\nfeld\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcPhJj5\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Based on your error message you should try updating rlang to at least version 0.4.10 before trying again

Comment: This is interesting. I went into the packages menu which said 0.4.5 is installed and 0.4.10 was available. I checked the box and hit "install updates" and restarted R as prompted. (I even closed and reopened R studio in case it would help).  After reopening R studio and going back into the same menu, it still said 0.4.5 was installed and 0.4.10 was available. It doesn't seem to detect that I just installed it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the error message to your question. It looks like there is a binary rlang v0.4.10 available for windows (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_0.4.10.zip). Download this file and install from within R using `install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)` and select the zip file from wherever you downloaded it. Once rlang is updated, try updating lifecycle/hms and see if it's successful or if it returns more errors.

Comment: Step 1 done. It's giving me this. Now updating...

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/nfeld/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Comment: Installing hms gives me the (now updated) markup which I have edited in the original post. When I try to import a dataset, it now says "number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)" - which I find quite odd considering I haven't even specified a file to import yet. But it's no longer giving me the error that I need the package hms.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the error messages - it makes troubleshooting waaay easier - the next step is to update "lifecycle". For both "hms" and "lifecycle" it says that there are binary packages available - these are what you want to install if possible as you seem to be having issues compiling the source code. When you try to update packages and it says "there are later packages available, do you want to build from source?" select "No" (don't say "Yes", even though it seems counterintuitive), and update your question to include the output.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just went into the cran.r-project.org website and manually downloaded both lifecycle and hms using the zip files in the same way I did for rlang. It's giving me the same error: `number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)`

Comment: The package viewer now does in fact display hms version 1.0.0 when I use the search tool. So it appears to have installed correctly when I went in by hand. The error I am now receiving, I'm guessing, is unrelated to packages being absent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231633/discussion-between-nathan-feldman-and-jared-mamrot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to reinstall R/Rstudio and all required packages. I believe this was caused by a known issue with incompatible package versions (https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/179) and potentially had to do with installing R packages into a OneDrive folder.